# 'so…as' vs. 'so…that'

Tags: grammar

This test is really confusing me. I thought both 'so...as' and 'so...that' are correct structures to be used in cause-and-effect events. However, I can't understand why option 1 is incorrect.

> Climatic shifts are ......... at first from ordinary fluctuations in
>   the weather.
>
> 1. so gradual as to be indistinguishable
> 2. enough gradual not to be distinguishable
> 3. gradual enough so that one cannot distinguish them as such
> 4. so gradual that they cannot be distinguished (correct answer)

I really thank whom can shed a light on this and acknowledge me why option 1 can't be correct.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with option 1. It's a little awkward, modifying the adjective  _indistinguishable_ with the phrase _at first_, but I find it perfectly grammatical.

Comment: I agree with @ColinFine both 1 and 4 seem fine to me

Comment: I'd just add that this isn't a cause-and-effect statement. It means simply "so gradual that they are indistinguishable..."